# Getting property names using JSONPath and Json.Net

Tags: json.net, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

Is there a way to use JSONPath with Json.Net to get the property names in a nested json.

To be clear, here is a sample json:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "hum": 48.1,
    "temp": 24.4
  }
}
```

What I need in this case is `temp` and `hum`.

I saw some implementations where they support the usage of a tilde (~) in the jsonPath to fetch that information. For reference: https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath

So in this case it would mean something like `$.fields.*~`

I tried using the online demo of that lib and it works like a charm but I need that feature in dotnet core and I can't find it.

Comment: Does it have to be a pure [tag:jsonpath] solution?  You can easily get the property names with [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), e.g. `JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("$.fields").Children<JProperty>().Select(p => p.Name)`

Comment: I would definitely prefer to stick to jsonpath only but I will investigate this workaround and see if it will work in this context